# Will I ever need the UIApplication* application from the ApplicationDelegate functions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

When would the application parameter in any of the app delegates not be equal to the shared instance?

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{  
  UIApplication* sharedapp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  if(application == sharedapp){
    //things are as I expect
  }else{
    //some other situation I can't think of
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea of the `application` parameter is so you don't need to call `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there wouldn't be any situation like that.

From Documentation:

> Every app has exactly one instance of **UIApplication**. When an app is launched, the system calls the UIApplicationMain function; among its other tasks, this function creates a singleton UIApplication object. Thereafter you access the object by calling the sharedApplication class method.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` will **always** return a pointer to your app's shared application object. That's what the method is for.

What is the variable `sharedApp` you are comparing against? Presumably that's an instance variable that you defined and set to contain a pointer to your application object with an identical call to `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This is just an illustration of my question.  I am scratching my head on why the delegate would have application passed in if its available via [UIApplication sharedApplication].... I suppose its just there for convenience, since maybe a common pattern is to update the badge?